# Comparing AIC of Tensor Product Smooths versus Thin Plate Splines

Tags: r, aic, generalized-additive-model, splines, mgcv

I'm comparing the AIC of these two models.

Tensor Product Smooth vs. Thin Plate Spline both fit using **REML**

```
library(mgcv)

ThinPlateSpline <- gam(Z ~ s(X1, X2, bs="tp", k = 17), data = DF,  method="REML")
TensorProductSmooth <- gam(Z ~ te(X1, X2, k = 6), data = DF,  method="REML")

AIC(ThinPlateSpline, TensorProductSmooth)
```

Is the AIC comparison mathematically justifiable, if not, why not?

Comment: Hi @Brad, did you get/ find an answer to your question yet? I'm interested in this issue too.

Comment: @Jade Not yet. Might bounty it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the use of the AIC would not be justifiable? Using the AIC requires that 1) you have a sufficiently high number of observations and 2) that these observations are i.i.d., is it the case for your DF data?

Comment: Possible different under the hood transformations of the input that that the user could be unaware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AIC is valid for my question. It's confirmed in the book:

**Generalized Additive Models: An Introduction with R (SECOND EDITION), by Simon Wood**

**BRAIN IMAGING EXAMPLE:**

```
m2 <- gam(medFPQ~s(Y,X,k=100),data=brain,family=Gamma(link=log))
tm <- gam(medFPQ~te(Y,X,k=10),data=brain,family=Gamma(link=log))
tm1 <- gam(medFPQ ~ s(Y,k=10,bs="cr") + s(X,bs="cr",k=10) + ti(X,Y,k=10), data=brain, family=Gamma(link=log))
AIC(m1,m2,m3)
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory AIC does not require the models to be from the same family. So you can compare models with different forms.
But in practice some implementations omit constants from the likelihood function as they're not necessary for comparison of models from the same family (for example two linear regressions). This can cause errors when comparing models with different likelihood functions.

So you need to check before using any implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The original formulation of the AIC requires that the different observations that you use to fit your model are i.i.d.. If this condition is met, you can safely use the AIC to compare both of your models.

I highly recommend the following seminal paper on the AIC and the BIC:

[Burnham, K. P., & Anderson, D. R. (2004). Multimodel inference: understanding AIC and BIC in model selection. Sociological methods & research, 33(2), 261-304](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/0049124104268644?casa_token=ZRP-pX0u_PYAAAAA:0z_thOCx-EDYqGH2LicUpILNYn-EyS-mFMrDe12CdDh4DN7QuRQAZ8VL42dON2Xki4hJa3uBMEaF).

Just a side note: in this very interesting [recent paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.spa.2020.10.006), the authors extend the use of the BIC to some cases of correlated observations, and especially to the case of time-invariant Hidden Markov Models.

Regarding the "under the hood transformations" you mentioned, and adding on leviva's answer, one should be careful about the `AIC` function (I remember, when using the `spatstats` package, that the function used an incorrect number of free parameters). You can easily alleviate this issue by computing the AIC yourself using the likelihood of both your models.